# IPython Notebook doesn't show full namespace

Tags: namespaces, jupyter-notebook

I am new to IPython and this seems like a simple question, but I have not been able to resolve it.

In the IPython notebook (via Anaconda3) When I run:

```
sum   # simple builtin function
```

Output:

```
<function sum>
```

Instead, I would expect output to be:

```
<function builtins.sum>
```

Thoughts, suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the namespace with:

```
dir(len)
```

I noticed the following:

```
sum.__module__
```

Output:

```
'builtins'
```

@Gerard Rozsavolgyi's repr() suggestion was the initial way I used to addresse my concern (+1), but I feel the **module** attribute gives an output more suitable for playing with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's not the expected output, but it may be because you can launch ipython notebook with options like :

```
ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

and then it's not any more the sum built-in which is used but something like:

```
<function numpy.core.fromnumeric.sum>.
```

So ipython notebook adds it's own layer

For **len** we have an output of

```
<function len>
```

and **repr(len)** giving the expected output :

```
<built-in function len>
```